# Combating addAttachment in PHPMail

Tags: php, phpmailer, joomla3.0

Health to all, dear programmers. In the Joomla 3 module, I try to add a field to the feedback form with the addition of a file. The letter comes, and as it were there is an attachment, but there are solid numbers and letters without an extension and 0kb. Here it is added:

```
 <?php $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['uploaded-file']['name']));
    $filename = $_FILES['uploaded-file']['name'];
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded-file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);

    } else {
        $msg .= 'Failed to move file to ' . $uploadfile;
    }
    $mailSender->addAttachment($uploadfile); ?>

<label>
<input class="uploaded-file" id="uploaded-file" type="file" name="uploaded-file"/>
<span id="text_fileup">Add File</span>
</label>
```

I know something is missing, revised a lot, but I still do not understand what is there. Thanks for earlier, who will prompt the right decision. +100500 in your karma.✌

Comment: Is your PHPMailer instance called `mail` or `mailSender`? Why are you attaching the same file twice, and once even it fails verification?

Comment: @Synchro, in the module so it was $ mailSender, it's me the third-party code in the example peeped. but then fixed $ mail on $ mailSender, still do not come with the file ..
Yes, I understood the error .. but I've already reconsidered the variants that nothing happened ..

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with similar code on
[github.com](https://github.com/sosojni/joomla-contact-module)

Thank you very much Stjepan Osojnički.

True, you need to make some settings in the module that would be sent, apparently the module is not written. Namely:

Exact URL - off

Disable HTTPS - on

Fixed URL - off